# Proving that $(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)^2 = n(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)$ $\space$ in $\space$ $\mathbb{F}[x] / \langle x^n - 1 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How would one prove that

$(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)^2 = n(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)$ $\space$  in $\space$ $\mathbb{F}[x] / \langle x^n - 1 \rangle$,

meaning

$(x^{n-1}+...+x+1)^2 - n(x^{n-1}+...+x+1) \in \langle x^n - 1 \rangle $.

I know that $x^n - 1 = (x^{n-1}+...+x+1)(x-1) $, but I don't know where to go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $p(x)^2-np(x) = p(x)(p(x)-n)$ and if $p(1) = n$, then $x-1|p(x) -n$

Comment: If we write $p=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}+\langle x^n-1\rangle$ for this coset, it follows that $xp=p$. Consequently $x^ip=p$ for all $i$, and the claim follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to do it with combinatorics (the finiteness assumption on the field seems to be inconsequential).

Indeed, it is easy to check that
$(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\dots+x+1)^2$
equals
$$
1+2x+3x^2+\dots+(n-1)x^{n-2}+n x^{n-1}+(n-1)x^{n}+\dots+2x^{2n-3}+x^{2n-2},
$$
namely, the coefficients increase from $1$ to $n$ to then decrease to $1$ again.
This directly implies the statement in the quotient by the ideal generated by $x^n-1$.

To see the above, it is enough to look at the powers $x^k$ for $k\leq n-1$, because the square of a palyndromic polynomials is palyndromic. Expanding
$$
(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)^2=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n-1}x^{i+j}
$$
we discover that the coefficient in front of $x^k$ in $(x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)^2$ is the number of ways of writing $k=i+j$ for integers $0\leq i,j\leq n-1$, which is clearly $k+1$ if $k\leq n-1$.

Comment: This works, too :-)